# Array in foreachloop returns additional null value

Tags: php, json

I have a problem in php.
So, i have a json data which i will decode and put in object
Then, i will use foreach function for gettings the parameters.
I'll be putting this to a array so i can call it outside of the loop.
However,when i'm displaying the results it returns a additional null value like this:

```
[{"mobile":"639179512744"},{"mobile":"639054971214"}, {"mobile":"639394297841"},{"mobile":"639296378818"},{"mobile":"639265161309"},{"mobile":null}]
```

Where the last record should not be included. I only have 5 records of mobile.

Here is my code:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = (object)json_decode($data);
$model = $data->data;
$model = json_encode($model);
$model = json_decode($model);
$model = (object)$model;
foreach($model AS $row){
  $mobile = $row->mobile_number;
   $array[] = array(
          'mobile'=>$mobile
    );

}

echo json_encode($array);
```

And here is the data:

```
{"action":"upload","data":[{"mobile_number":"639179512744","sentdt":"2017-    02-07 00:21:57","imsi":"","remarks":"ACTIVE"},    {"mobile_number":"639054971214","sentdt":"2017-02-07     00:21:57","imsi":"","remarks":"ACTIVE"},    {"mobile_number":"639394297841","sentdt":"2017-02-07     00:21:57","imsi":"","remarks":"Absent Subscriber - No International Mobile     Subscriber Identity"},{"mobile_number":"639296378818","sentdt":"2017-02-07  00:21:58","imsi":"","remarks":"Absent Subscriber - No International Mobile  Subscriber Identity"},{"mobile_number":"639265161309","sentdt":"2017-02-07  00:21:58","imsi":"","remarks":"ACTIVE"},{}]}
```

Someone can help?I want to get rid of the additional null value
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could try doing a null check, like this:

```
foreach($model as $row){
  if (!is_null($row->mobile_number)) {
    $array[] = array(
      'mobile'=> $row->mobile_number;
    );
  }
}
```

Also note that there is no reason to cache $row->mobile_number in a variable, just pass it straight in to the array.

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem.

```
foreach($model AS $row){
  $mobile = $row->mobile_number;

  if(!empty($mobile) && isset($mobile)){      
     $array[] = array(
          'mobile'=>$mobile
     );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your end of data is:

```
...ACTIVE"},{}]}
```

When data decoded, the last of array value is empty object, that means last of array value not have member variable of `mobile_number`, so execute `$row->mobile_number;` can get value of `null`, and PHP error reporting will be reported a `E_NOTICE` error at the same time.

You can use function `is_null()` to filter null value, but you should be to check your data source at the same time.